# pyQt imshow is not updating

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt, imshow

I am trying to update a matrix and show it using Qt with imshow, but it is not updating and I get a warning that the variable room is shadowing another room.
This is my code in Qt using imshow:(After defining the required libraries, the matrix "room" initializes as zero. Then a form designed in Qt Designer, with a widget called "mplt_widget" and a push button called "start_PB")

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigCanv

# Initializing existence of wave in the room (0)
room = [[0.0 for mm in range(0, 100)] for nn in range(0, 100)]

plt.ion()

Form = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "FTDT.ui"))[0]


class PlotWin(QMainWindow, Form):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Form.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.fig = plt.figure(frameon=True)
        self.ax = Axes3D(self.fig)
        self.canvas = FigCanv(self.fig)

        self.line1 = []
        self.line1.append(self.ax.imshow(room))

        l = QVBoxLayout(self.mplt_widget)
        l.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.PlotThread = PlotThread(0)
        self.start_PB.clicked.connect(self.start)

    def start(self):
        num = np.random.random()
        self.PlotThread = PlotThread(num)
        self.PlotThread.update_trigger.connect(self.update_plot)
        self.PlotThread.start()

    def update_plot(self, room):
        self.line1.set_data(room)
        self.canvas.draw()


class PlotThread(QtCore.QThread):
    update_trigger = QtCore.pyqtSignal(np.ndarray, np.ndarray)

    finished_trigger = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, decay):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.decay = decay

    def run(self):
        for Time in range(10):

            for mm in range(0, 100):
                for nn in range(0, 100):
                    room[mm][nn] += self.decay*(room[mm][nn]/2 + 1/2)

            self.update_trigger.emit(room)
            sleep(1)

        self.finished_trigger.emit()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle("Fusion")
w = PlotWin()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please import the needed libraries first

Comment: Please correct the indents in order to be able to copy paste the code as well

Comment: Remove the extra code and provide a minimum working example to illustrate the error.

Comment: Thank you for your warnings. The required changes have been done.

Comment: `FDTD.ui` is missing, unable to run the program. Looking into it maybe you should do `self.line1.extend(self.ax.imshow(room))` or `self.line1, = self.ax.imshow(room)`